# Progressbar in Python

Tags: python, optimization

i wish to improve my Progressbar in Python

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import time

class Progress(object):
    def __init__(self, maxval):
        self._seen = 0.0
        self._pct = 0
        self.maxval = maxval

    def update(self, value):
        self._seen = value
        pct = int((self._seen / self.maxval) * 100.0)
        if self._pct != pct:
            sys.stderr.write("|%-100s| %d%%" % (u"\u2588"*pct, pct) + '\n')
            sys.stdout.flush()
        self._pct = pct

    def start(self):
        pct = int((0.0 / self.maxval) * 100.0)
        sys.stdout.write("|%-100s| %d%%" % (u"\u2588"*pct, pct) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def finish(self):
        pct = int((self.maxval / self.maxval) * 100.0)
        sys.stdout.write("|%-100s| %d%%" % (u"\u2588"*pct, pct) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

toolbar_width = 300
pbar = Progress(toolbar_width)
pbar.start()
for i in xrange(toolbar_width):
    time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
    pbar.update(i)
pbar.finish()
```

Comment: CodeReview is to get review on code which is working, not to get some help to add a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, I've not sure SE.CodeReview is the right place to get the help you are looking for.

However, as I didn't read your question properly at first, I had a look at your code and changed a few things (please note that it's not exactly the same behavior as it used to be):

- extract the display logic in a method on its own
- reuse update in start and finish (little changes here : this method now updates the object instead of just doing some display)
- removed self._seen because it didn't seem useful

Here the code :

```
class Progress(object):
    def __init__(self, maxval):
        self._pct = 0
        self.maxval = maxval

    def update(self, value):
        pct = int((value / self.maxval) * 100.0)
        if self._pct != pct:
            self._pct = pct
            self.display()

    def start(self):
        self.update(0)

    def finish(self):
        self.update(self.maxval)

    def display(self):
        sys.stdout.write("|%-100s| %d%%" % (u"\u2588"*self._pct, self._pct) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thank Josay for the review. What i wish to do is print the percentage (1%, 2%, 3%, ..., 100%) in the middle of the progress bar.

Comment: @Gianni unfortunately, that's off-topic for Code Review. You should edit your question to be a valid code review request as defined in the [faq], otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: @codesparkle it's a fuzzy definition about SO (= stackoverflow) or CR (code review). Normally people use this approach: code works CR, code doesn't work SO, no code Programmer. In my case the code works and i want to improve the quality. With a with a working code (no error) i think (maybe i wrong) this question is more appropriate in CD